# Visual Studio 2015 Dark Theme suddenly makes code disappear

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Was wondering if anyone is familiar with this issue...

I'm using VS 2015 Community in a VMWare virtual machine (Win10) with some C# solution and today all of a sudden most the code disappears, except for a few variable names. Strangely enough this only happens on the Dark theme, not on the white or blue theme.

Switching between themes, closing/reopening solution, etc. didn't help. This never happened before and I've been using VS2015 in the VM for weeks without problems. Does anyone know of a fix for this?

Comment: You might consider trying to do the following, from the IDE menu select Tools, Import Export setting then select Reset all settings, then follow pressing next.

Comment: Disappears = `gets deleted` or `becomes invisible to the eye`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem! The text scaling was somehow accidentally switched to 110% and the font I'm using obviously is not OK with this. Switching back to 100% fixed it. What's odd though is that it works even with scaled text on white/blue theme with same font.